# Understanding VML shadow matrix

Tags: android, internet-explorer, matrix, vml, skia

I am working on a MS-Word rendering tool for Android. I need to render shadows for vml shapes. Microsoft's documentation on shadow matrix is not very clear and I couldn't find detailed explanation on vml shadow matrix on the web.

According to Microsoft documentation shadow matrix contains 6 values, 4 scale values and 2 perspective values ([refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.vml.shadow(v=office.14).aspx)).

[**Sxx, Sxy, Syx, Syy, Px, Py**] S stands for 'Scale', P stands for 'Perspective '

My doubts:

1. Android's transformation matrix supports ScaleX and ScaleY, only two scale values. How do I map VML's 4 scale values to Android's transformation matrix?
2. What those suffix values mean? What is the difference between Sxy and Syx?

Any explanation, even if it is partial, will be really helpful.

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: see `Matrix#setPolyToPoly` or `Matrix#setValues` if you are a math guru

Comment: Hi pskink, tx for the reply. I know those APIs, but i do not know how to convert the 4 scale values of VML into 2 scale scale values of Android.